# What is the best way to parse a non-flat file format in Java?

Tags: java, file, parsing, format

I am attempting to parse a nested file format in Java.

The file format looks like this:

```
head [

    A [
        property value
        property2 value
        property3 [
            ... down the rabbit hole ...
        ]
    ]

    ... more As ...

    B [
        .. just the same as A
    ]

    ... more Bs ...
]
```

What is the best/easiest technique to parse this into my program?

- Finite State Machine?
- Manually read it word by word and keep track of what part of the structure I am in?
- Write a grammar...?

*As a side note, I have no control over the format - because I knew someone would say it!*

Comment: the file elements will be recursive, similar to XML?

Comment: @ShamimHafiz Yes, the properties can have properties - I'll update my example.

Comment: Do want to end up with a structure in memory that matches the structure of the flat file (similar to DOM if you were parsing XML) or do you want to actions as you see each parsed element [SAX-like]?

Comment: I want to hit actions on each element, SAX-like I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the grammar is indeed nested like this, writing a very simple [top-down parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_parsing) would be a trivial task: you have very few tokens to recognize, and the nested structure repeats itself very conveniently for a textbook [recursive-descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

I would not even bother with ANTLR or another parser generator for something this simple, because the learning curve would eat the potential benefits for the project<sup>*</sup> .

---

<sup>*</sup>  Potential benefits for you from learning a parser generator are hard to overestimate: if you can spend a day or two learning to build parsers with ANTLR, your view of structured text files will change forever.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my example - it can nested for a ways down.

Comment: Regarding your edit, it's funny you mention parser generators. If you look at my question history you'll see I've started to learn about one in Python. It just seems a little bit overkill for this one-off project.

Comment: @sdasdadas There is always a balance between the immediate benefits vs. long-term ones. ANTLR is an amazing tool, but it takes some time to get used to. Given your grammar with only three non-terminals, to me this would feel a little like using heavy artillery to shoot a fly.

Answer (score 1):

I second the recommendation to take a look at Antlr.   StAX adds SAX-like event handling.

http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Interfacing+StAX+to+ANTLR

Yes there is a learning curve, but by the time you handled all the odd cases and debugged your code, you'd probably break even -- pluse you'd have a new item on your resume.

Answer (score 1):

Arguably the easiest way to parse files of these kinds is using a recursive descent parser (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). I guess this is what you mean by manually reading and keeping track of the structure you have found.

A finite state machine wouldn't work if you have to be able to deal with unlimited nesting. If there are only two levels it could be enough.

Writing a grammar and generating a parser would also work, but if you haven't done that before or don't have the time to learn how to use the tools it's probably overkill...

Answer (score 0):

The fastest approach is to use a format like this already e.g. JSon or YAML.  These formats do this and are supported.

> As a side note, I have no control over the format

If you want to know the best way to parse something like Yaml, but not, is to read the code for a simple Yaml parser.

Just parsing the file is unlikely to be enough, you will also want to trigger events or generate a data model from the data you load.

Comment: The OP already said  he has not control of the input format so this answer is not helpful.

Comment: @DaleWilson If you don't bother reading my answer, its not going to be helpful.  I already addressed the fact he can't change the format.